# Is Yahweh in the Old Testament not Jesus Christ in the New Testament?

Tags: jesus, hebrew-bible

The Apostles seems to reference him as "Son". We find at several places, New Testament authors citing Old Testament passages referring to Yahweh and yet applies them to the "Son" (e.g., compare Ps. 102:25-27 with Heb. 1:10-12; Isa. 6:1-10 with John 12:39-41; Isa. 8:12-13 with 1 Pet. 3:14-15; Isa. 45:23 with Phil. 2:10-11; Joel 2:32 with Rom. 10:13).

Is this not clear enough that The Yahweh of the Old Testament is Jesus Christ in the New?

Comment: This is a theological synthesis question, and so off-topic. Most questions about the divinity of Jesus belong at [Christianity.se]

Comment: I have gotten my answer already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the consistent teachings of the NT is that Jesus is YHWH, Jehovah of the OT.  The NT regularly takes OT title (many unique to YHWH) and applies them to Jesus.

| OT Jehovah/YHWH | NT Jesus Christ |
| --- | --- |
| "My Lord" Ps 35:23 (LXX: κύριός μου) Ps 110:1 | "My Lord" John 20:13, 28, Luke 1:43, Phil 3:8, Matt 22:44, Mark 12:36, Luke 20:42, Acts 2:34 |
| Glory not shared, Isa 42:8, 48:11 | Glory with the Father, John 17:5, 24 |
| "Rock" Isa 44:8; Deut 32:3,4,15; Ps 92:15 | "that Rock was Christ" 1 Cor 10:4; Matt 16:18 |
| Bridegroom, Isa 49, 54, Jer 2, Hosea | Jesus is the Bridegroom of the church, Mark 2:19, Matt 9:15, Luke 5:34, 35 |
| Worship only YHWH, Ex 20:3, 34:14; Deut 8:19; 2 Kings 17:35-38 | Jesus worshiped, Matt 2:11, 14:33, 28:9, 17; Luke 4:8; 24:52; John 9:38; Rom 10:9, Heb 1:5, 6, Phil 2:10; Rev 5:6-12. |
| Searches hearts and minds, Jer 11:20, 17:10, 1 Sam 16:7 | Searches hearts and minds, Rev 2:23 |
| John 17:3 - source of eternal life | 1 John 5:11, 12, John 11;25, 14:6, 6":35-51 - Jesus is the source of eternal life |
| Ps 23:1 - "The LORD is my Shepherd". See also Isa 40:11, Eze 34:11 | John 10:11-16 - "I am the Good Shepherd". See also Heb 13:20, 1 peter 2:25, 5:4, Rev 7:17 |
| Ps 27:1 - "The LORD is my Light". See also Micah 7:8 | John 8:12 - "I am the light of the world". See also John 1:9, 9:5, 1 John 1:5-7. |
| Isa 44:24, 45:18 - Creator alone | John 1:3, 10, Col 1:16, 17, Heb 1:2 - Jesus created all things |
| Isa 43:3, 11, 45:17, 21 - Savior of all, alone. | Matt 1:21; Acts 4:12; 2 Tim 1:10; Tit 1:4, 2:13, 3:6; 2 Pet 1:1, 11 - Jesus is the only Savior. |
| Isa 41:4, 44:6, 48:12 - "First and Last" | Rev 1:17, 18, 2:8, 22:13 - "First and Last" |
| Deut 10:17, Ps 136:3, 26 "LORD of Lords" | Rev 17:14, 19:16 "Lord of lords" |
| Deut 10:17, Josh 3:11, 13, Ps 97:5, Zech 4:14, 6:5, Mic 4:13, - "LORD of All" | Acts 10:36, Rom 10:12, Col 1:15 - "Lord of All" |
| Zech 4:10 (& Zech 3:9) - seven eyes of the LORD | Rev 5:6 (Lamb) "seven eyes" |

Many OT passages about YTHWH are quoted in the NT applying to Jesus.  Here is a sample:

| Old Testament, about YHWH | New Testament about Jesus |
| --- | --- |
| Deut 32:43 (LXX) | Heb 1:6 |
| Ps 45:6, 7 | Heb 1:8, 9 |
| Ps 102:25 - 27. | Heb 1:10 - 12. |
| Isa 45:23 | Phil 2:10, 11, Rom 14:11 |
| Isa 40:3 | Matt 3:3 (cf v11) |
| Joel 2:32 | Rom 10:13 |
| Ps 31:5 (Eccl 12:7) | Acts 7:59 |
| Isa 52:6 | John 4:26 |

We even have numerous prayers being offers directly to Jesus such as: John 4:10, 14:13, 14, Acts 1:24, Acts 7:59, 60, 9:5, 10-14, 1 Cor 1:1, 2, 16:22, 2 Cor 12:8, 9,  1 Tim 1:12, Rev 5:8-13, 22:20, 1 Thess 3:11-14, 2 Thess 2:16, 17.

There are also instances where the OT gives the title "I AM" to YHWH such as Ex 3:13-15; Deut 32:39, Isa 41:4, 43:10, 13, 25, 45:19, 46:4, 48:12, 51:12, 52:6 (LXX).  In the NT, Jesus is the only one to use this title as His personal identifier: Mark 6:50, Mark 13:6, 14:27, 62, Luke 21:8, 22:70, John 4:26, 6:20, 8:24, 28, 58, 13:9, 18:5-8.